# If data field has value, display block separate div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<span>{{pstCntrl.doctorProfile.boardCertification ? === 'Yes' : $yes.display-block}}</span>
```

---

```
<span class="yes">Yes</span>
```

---

```
span.yes { 
    display:none;
}
```

The above is what I'm trying to do in Angular.JS, I am trying to simply display `block` my span div .`yes` *if* my `boardCertification` data field has the value of `yes`.

Comment: The construction of [a ternary operator is `condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) -- you've got your `?` in the middle of your condition...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use classes, you can use `ng-class` like this:

```
<span class="yes" ng-class="{ 'show': pstCntrl.doctorProfile.boardCertification === 'Yes' }">Yes</span>
```

with the css:

```
.show { 
    display: display-block;
}
```

If you want to just show or hide span, use `ng-if` :

```
<span ng-if="pstCntrl.doctorProfile.boardCertification === 'Yes'">Yes</span>
```